# Adding dynamic information to info bubble

Tags: javascript

I know my question may seem as s duplicate, but it really is not. There are different way to do it and I like my code... My code works mostly and I just want to figure out the infowindow content part., without rewriting it all.

I am looping through a list of businesses and plot the markers on a map. Everything works fine, until I add infowindow, which opens on click. While I was able to make it open next to the right point, the value inside always  belongs to the latest mapmarker. How can I fix that?

```
for (var i = 0; i < restaurants.length; i++) {
    var restaurant = restaurants[i];
    var customlabl = (restaurant[5] != 0 ? "$"+restaurant[5] : false );
    var customtitl = (restaurant[5] != 0 ? restaurant[0]+" -- "+restaurant[5] : restaurant[0]);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: customtitl
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
            lat: restaurant[1], 
            lng: restaurant[2]
        },
        map: map,           
        title:  customtitl,
        label:  customlabl
    });
    marker.addListener("click", function() {
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

In the above code, am able to open infowindow correctly. So, I modified it now to pick label or title from the marker into content.

```
marker.addListener("click", function() {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infowindow.content(title, this);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});
```

For some reason this breaks the functionality and infowindow is not opening any longer. What's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well content is not defined in the google.maps.InfoWindow but in InfoWindowOptions object.

So to make it work try change it to something like this:

```
marker.addListener("click", function() {
  let infoOptions = {
    content: 'hello world'
  };

  let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoOptions);
  infowindow.open(map, this);
});
```

or

```
let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: 'hello world'});
```

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks, but how do I add dynamic content? When I replace 'hello world' with customtitl I get the one from the last rendered marker.

Comment: you just set {content: this.title} in the event listener for the marker, that should work.